# Formating Django TimeField in a Django view

Tags: python, django

How do you format a TimeField in a Django view?

Currently in my django html template I can easily do something like: `{{movie.start_time|time:"g:iA"|lower}}`

How can I do the equivalent of the above in a Django view?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python `strftime()` function.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: This answer is ok, but seems to loose the flexibility of the django template time formatting. For example, how would I display 'AM' or 'PM' in lowercase?

Comment: Also times that are in the 12 hour format are displayed with leading zeros, which is undesirable. The closest I can get to the django time filter mentioned above is `movie.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")`. In this case, the hour has a leading zero and 'AM' and 'PM' are capitalized, which is incorrect for my display purposes.

Comment: You can always hand-process the results from `strftime()` if you have special requirements, i.e. call `lower()` on the result string, which will translate `AM` to `am`.

Comment: Ok, but this is still a bit of work for something that a Django template filter can do in one line. This would mean I would still have to parse out the leading zeros for hours.

Comment: I need to return a formatted string and store it in an elastic search index.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to achieve this. It isn't ideal, but this is what I came up with.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time = now.time()

t = time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
t = t.lower()
t = list(t)

if t[0] == '0':
    t.pop(0)

t = ''.join(t)
print t
```